# How to update a JavaScript generated HTML variable

Tags: javascript, html, button, event-listener

I created this little background color changer just for fun and to play around with JS for a bit but I'm having a problem I don't really know how to solve.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Color picker</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <div>
        <button id="main_button" class="btn btn-danger">Change color</button>
      </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and my JS:

```
const button = document.querySelector("#main_button");

function randomColor(){
  let letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  let color = "#";
  for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
};

function changeBackground(){
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
};

function createParagraph(){
  let color = randomColor();
  const div = document.querySelector(".container");
  let par = document.createElement("p");
  par.innerHTML = "Current color is " + color;
  div.appendChild(par);
}

button.addEventListener("click", changeBackground);
button.addEventListener("click", createParagraph);
```

And this is my problem, every time I click on the button a new paragraph is being generated with the new color code. But I want the button to update the color code in the same paragraph.
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to change? Do you want the button's color to change onclick, the paragraph color background, or the text in the paragraph?

Comment: The whole body color changes. In the picture is dark blue but it changes every time you click the button. Also I'm pretty sure it doesn't show me the correct color code either but that's a different problem :D

Comment: You don't want your background to change? Then you have to remove the event listener that calls the changeBackground function

Comment: No, the background is supposed to change color. In term of functionality, it works correctly. I just need the paragraph to show me the correct HEX code and update it every time I click the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually creating a new `<p>`-element every time you call `createParagraph()`.

Instead, you can create a tag in your HTML beforehand, and save its reference (which you can get by querying for it using e.g. `document.querySelector()`) in a variable.
Then, you can change its content by assigning a new value to its `.textContent`-property.

Here a demonstration:

```js
var pElement = document.querySelector('#p-id');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  pElement.textContent = "This is its new text, assigned using the '.textContent'-property!";
});
```

```html
<button>Change &lt;p&gt;'s content!</button>
<p id="p-id">This is the initial text.</p>
```

An **important note** would be, that you are actually not displaying the current color-value. You are calling `randomColor()` twice: Once in `changeBackground()`, and once in `createParagraph()`, while the created color is only used for either assigning `<body>` a new background-color or being displayed using the `<p>`-tag.

To display the actually used color, you need to use the same String for both the assignment and the value of `<p>`'s content. You can do that by one of the following:

1. Write both use-cases in one function
2. Use another variable for the color
3. Use the value of `document.body.style.background` (or `.backgroundColor`, depending on what you used). However, this will return the color in a format like `rgb(123, 213, 132)`, which might be unwanted.

I'll show examples for points 1 and 2.

Point 1 could look like this:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('#main_button');
const pElement = document.querySelector('#p_id');

function randomColor(){
  let letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  let color = "#";
  for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function changeAndUpdateColor() {
  let color = randomColor();
  document.body.style.background = color;
  pElement.textContent = 'Current Color is ' + color;
}

button.addEventListener('click', changeAndUpdateColor);
```

```html
<button id="main_button">Change Color</button>
<p id="p_id"></p>
```

Point 2 could look like this:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('#main_button');
const pElement = document.querySelector('#p_id');
var color = '';

function randomColor(){
  let letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  let color = "#";
  for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function changeBackground() {
  document.body.style.background = color;
}

function updateParagraph() {
  pElement.textContent = 'Current Color is ' + color;
}

function getNewColor() {
  color = randomColor();
}

button.addEventListener('click', getNewColor);
button.addEventListener('click', changeBackground);
button.addEventListener('click', updateParagraph);
```

```html
<button id="main_button">Change Color</button>
<p id="p_id"></p>
```

However, using this many functions and listeners makes the code look clunky. Instead, you should make use of ES6's *[function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)* or *[arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)*.

When using a function expression, we can initialize and use the color-variable inside, making a global variable useless.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('#main_button');
const pElement = document.querySelector('#p_id');

function randomColor(){
  let letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  let color = "#";
  for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let color = randomColor();
  document.body.style.background = color;
  pElement.textContent = 'Current Color is ' + color;
});
```

```html
<button id="main_button">Change Color</button>
<p id="p_id"></p>
```

Speaking of *[global context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)*:
Declaring many variables and/or functions in the global context will pollute the global namespace, and will be accessible to the user e.g. using the browser-console. This is a problem for functions where sensitive data is handled or accessible.

To free up the global namespace, we can place most of our script inside a so called [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), an *immediately invoked function expression*. Adding this would be as simple as placing your code inside one like this:

```js
(function() {
  // Your code ...
})();
```

The brackets around the function expression itself will group it so it can be executed using the calling brackets `()`, much like placing a number inside brackets will allow us to call a function on it, like this:

```js
(123).toString();
```

One **further note** now would be, that *[function declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)* inside blocks (means: when not declared in the global context) are not part of ECMAScript, making this a non-standardized feature. This might be irrelevant to you, since it is supported in most (if not all) modern browsers anyway. However, in these cases, one should use function expressions referenced by a variable, e.g. like this:

```js
(function() {
  var aFunction = function() {
    // ...
  };
  
  aFunction(); // Executed as usual
})();
```

Note that function expressions are not hoisted, unlike function declarations, meaning they need to come before their usage in the code.
Accessing characters of a String like accessing entries of an array is another non-standardized feature, again supported in most browsers. The standardized way would be to use `String.charAt()`.

Refactoring your code could look like this:

```js
// Is OK to be globally accessible
function randomColor(){
  let letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  let color = "#";
  for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    color += letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 16));
  }
  return color;
}

// Should be placed inside an IIFE; the global context is still accessible
(function() {
  const button = document.querySelector('#main_button');
  const pElement = document.querySelector('#p_id');

  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let color = randomColor();
    document.body.style.background = color;
    pElement.textContent = 'Current Color is ' + color;
  });
})();
```

```html
<button id="main_button">Change Color</button>
<p id="p_id"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

on every click you are adding another p tag - instead create a p tag in your html page-

```
<p id="colorTag"><p>
```

in your createParagraph function -
instead of `let par = document.createElement("p");`  do `let par = document.getElementById('colorTag')  par.innerHTML = "Current color is " + color;`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you want to change the backgroundcolor to the newest paragraph color. Therefor you have to call the changebackground function in the createParagraph function:

```
function createParagraph(){
  let color = randomColor();
  const div = document.querySelector(".container");
  let par = document.createElement("p");
  par.innerHTML = "Current color is " + color;
  div.appendChild(par);
  changeBackground(color);
}

function changeBackground(newcolor){
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = newcolor;
};

button.addEventListener("click", createParagraph);
```

This would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You every time create a new paragraph -

HTML File :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0- 
      beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384- 
       giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <title>Color picker</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <div>
        <button id="main_button" class="btn btn-danger">Change color</button>
      </div>
      <p id="par"></p> <!-- <== You Need this for render every time color -->
    </div>

    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS File:

```
const button = document.querySelector("#main_button");

function randomColor() {
  let letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  let color = "#";
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function changeBackground() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
}

function createParagraph() {
  let color = randomColor();
  const div = document.querySelector(".container");
  let par = document.getElementById("par"); // select paragraph as html file
  par.innerHTML = "Current color is " + color; // and render color to paragraph
}

button.addEventListener("click", changeBackground);
button.addEventListener("click", createParagraph);
```